# Speed up summation using caching in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, memoization

In each of the `10000` iterations, we select the `player` with the least total score to play a game, where he will earn a random score.

I think the slowest part of the code in each iteration appears to be the summing of all the players score.

```
sum(g.score for g in players[x])
```

Since only one player's score is updated in each iteration, it seems that caching may help speed up the current `O(N)` implementation into a `O(1)`.

What is a good way to make use of caching? Thank you!

```
import random


class Game:
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score


players = {f"player{i}": [] for i in range(8)}

for i in range(10000):
    player = min(players, key=lambda x: sum(g.score for g in players[x]))
    players[player].append(Game(random.randint(0, 10)))

for player, games in players.items():
    print(player, ":", sum(g.score for g in games))
```

Comment: Maybe that or you can just for each iteration simply subtract the old score of the randomly chosen player and add the new score assigned to that player since this is the only thing that changes.

Answer (score 0):

#### One solution

One approach is to use a dictionary to keep track of the total score:

```
players = {f"player{i}": [] for i in range(8)}
total_player_score = dict.fromkeys(players, 0)

for i in range(10000):
    player = min(total_player_score, key=total_player_score.get)
    game = Game(random.randint(0, 10))
    players[player].append(game)
    total_player_score[player] += game.score

for player, games in players.items():
    print(player, ":", sum(g.score for g in games))
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
player0 : 6252
player1 : 6250
player2 : 6247
player3 : 6247
player4 : 6244
player5 : 6248
player6 : 6250
player7 : 6245
```

#### An even faster solution `(O(mlogn))`

On top of that, I suggest you use a heap, to keep track of the minimum:

```
import heapq

players = {f"player{i}": [] for i in range(8)}
total_player_score = [(0, player) for player in players]
heapq.heapify(total_player_score)

for i in range(10000):
    score, player = heapq.heappop(total_player_score)
    game = Game(random.randint(0, 10))
    players[player].append(game)
    heapq.heappush(total_player_score, (score + game.score, player))
```

This second approach converts the code from `O(m*n)` to `O(m*logn)` where `n` is the number of players and `m` the number of iterations (`range(1000)` in the code)

Comment: Is your first approach really O(n**2) or are you talking about the OP's code?

Comment: @Mark The first approach is `O(n**2)` because you do a `min`, well is not actually `O(n**2)` is `O(1000*n)`

Comment: @Updated the answer with some clarifications

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. The heap is a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you encapsulate the data and behavior in a `Player` class you can let that class keep track of the paperwork around totals so the caller of the class doesn't need to know about it. This lets you have code that's easy to ready and efficient at the expense of being a bit longer:

```
import random

class Game:
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = []
        self.total = 0
        
    def add_game(self, game):
        self.scores.append(game)
        self.total += game.score


players = [Player(f"player{i}") for i in range(8)]


for i in range(10000):
    player = min(players, key=lambda player: player.total)
    player.add_game(Game(random.randint(0, 10)))

for player in players:
    print(player.name, ":", player.total)
```

This prints with no noticeable delay:

```
player0 : 6280
player1 : 6281
player2 : 6283
player3 : 6280
player4 : 6279
player5 : 6283
player6 : 6277
player7 : 6283
```